# Pandas - Adding rows from one dataframe to the another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add manually row (one by one) from one dataframe to the another:

```
path = "...csv"

data = pd.read_csv(path, na_values='NULL')

path2 = "...csv"

data2 = pd.read_csv(path2, na_values='NULL')

for row in data2.itertuples():

     x = input("Do you want to add the row, please write Yes or No")

     if x=='Yes':

          data = data.append(row)

          print(data.shape)

     else:

         pass
```

Shape of those dataframes are: (1674, 83) (1727, 83). When I run this code I receive this error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'int'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Any ideas how to fix it? Can't find a good solution for it.

Comment: Please provide sample data, minimal example and expected output to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a Dataframe or Series to the append method.

So you can either convert every row in a Series and then append, like Ynjxsjmh said:

> DataFrame.itertuples returns a namedtuple, you can convert it to
> dictionary with ._asdict() and create a one row DataFrame
>
> df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame([row._asdict()]).set_index('Index'))

or you can store all the result you want to append in a list and then create a Dataframe from that list and append it all at once.

```
path = "...csv"

data = pd.read_csv(path, na_values='NULL')

path2 = "...csv"

data2 = pd.read_csv(path2, na_values='NULL')

result = list()

for row in data2.itertuples():

    x = input("Do you want to add the row, please write Yes or No")

    if x == 'Yes':

        result.append(row)

        print(data.shape)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(result)

data = pd.concat(data, df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.itertuples` returns a namedtuple, you can convert it to dictionary with `._asdict()` and create a one row DataFrame

```py
df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame([row._asdict()]).set_index('Index'))
# or
df1 = pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame([row._asdict()]).set_index('Index')])
```